# Removing event handler in C#

Tags: c#, windows-8, event-handling, windows-store

I am developing a Windows Store app, in which a page consumes an event, registering an handler in this way:

```
CommandQueue.CommandPushed += commandQueue_QueueChanged;
```

now, when leaving the page, in the "OnNavigatedFrom, I'm trying to remove handler in this way:

```
CommandQueue.CommandPushed -= commandQueue_QueueChanged;
```

but the handler isn't actually removed. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: It is hard to answer to that kind of question, because not enough information. Where you register handler? Maybe you register handler more than one time?

Comment: The handler is registered only one time in the page's constructor.

Comment: Normally that shoudl work. Are you sure the program is running through your 'OnNavigatedFrom'-Method?

Comment: I'm absolutely sure.
The problem is that this code is big like a giant elephant. Maybe I did some mistake somewhere.

Comment: It was the second: I made a lot of mistakes with event and handlers. The problem is that having an event with a lot of handlers in a lot of classes drives me crazy.

Comment: @PierpaoloIlConteParis How you resolve the issue. I am facing the same issue now. But i created the event handler only one time in the constructor. I am sure no where i created more.